Connection timed out in Laravel Application on Live Server
I am deploying an application on aruba hosting. I have basic linux hosting package, in which I do not have terminal access. I was once able to connect to database, don't know how! I have tried putting a simple test.php file on the server and it connected to database successfully. Another important thing is that this application is developed in Vue and Laravel. I am not much familiar with Vue to find a way to test it with Vue.
Here is .env file
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ifOG0g1R9hF3I3F67Ubpui5mw3Qx8Ji5svBdVk4Dgqo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://www.riverstudio.it/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=31.11.39.155
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password

I have tried everything I could, changing DB_HOST value to localhost and mysql.aruba.it. But none of it worked.
Here is the test.php file
<?php
$host = '31.11.39.155';
$port = '3306';
$dbname = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Database connection successful!";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

What are the ways to fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated

why are you trying to connect the db using the core php?

Have you tried to contact your hosting providers support? This is clearly about you not knowing the right credentials to use.

@Platinum Yes I have tried contacting support and they said that in order to run laravel you need SSH access. Therefore, upgrade hosting package. That is confusing because whatever hosting provide, I have used in the past even if SSH access was not granted ran laravel.

@sandipbharadva I was testing if database connects successfully.

@QasimAli that you can also check by using the command php artisan migrate. If the database connection is correct then it will create new table else fire the error

@sandipbharadva Thank you. I have mentioned in my post that unfortunately, I do not have access to shell. That brings more trouble

@QasimAli do you get any error? if yes then please share here

I doubt your DB credentials are 'username' and 'password'

@QasimAli you don't have to tell them you are running laravel, just ask how to get the db credentials.
